# DHL Notification - Receive package without ordering

Tags: germany

Today, I receive a notification from DHL that a company named Brand Addition Gmbh Hagen, that they have sent me a package. I have neither heard of the company, nor ordered anything from them. I also dont expect any package at the moment. This company knows my full name (which i dont use for online shopping) and my address.

Can anyone please tell me if this has ever happened to you and if this is a scam?

I´m thinking about not receiving the package and it will be automatically returned to the company after 7 days.

Comment: I received  the notification on the DHL App

Comment: Related: [Shipped package arrived - didn't order, possible scam?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/110824/shipped-package-arrived-didnt-order-possible-scam), [Received a package but didn't order it](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/114928/received-a-package-but-didnt-order-it), [Unexpected goods delivery - is this a scam, and what kind of scam?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/131097/unexpected-goods-delivery-is-this-a-scam-and-what-kind-of-scam)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected goods delivery - is this a scam, and what kind of scam?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/131097/unexpected-goods-delivery-is-this-a-scam-and-what-kind-of-scam)

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the DHL app, but is it reasonable to assume that if the notification came via the app, then DHL does in fact have possession of an actual package they are shipping to you? Does DHL provide a means of contact to request further details about this package?

Comment: Their website says *We create branded merchandise, retail & gift items, and packaging to support great brands globally* Maybe you ordered something personalized and they fulfill the order. Looks legit, to me!

Comment: What happened, eventually?